# Minimum unfinished basement door height

Tags: doors, basement, code-compliance, crawlspace

I have a 1927 house that is built on a hill such that the basement walks out level with side yard and the sub-basement originally had a door that walked out the back yard with two steps down to ground level

floor above the sub-basement has been lowered such that the ceiling height is only 6'2". The original door and windows were removed and filled with cinder blocks.

I would like to open the door opening back up and put in a short steel door, but it would be substantially less than 6'since there is a substantial threshold and a ledger board at the ceiling.

The other less desirable possibility would be to put a window in the old door opening.  Is there code requirements or  any other reasons I could not put a very short door in the old opening?

If the door were out-swing, could I just let the top of the door overlap with the ledger board?

Thank you in advance for any advice you have.

Comment: You essentially have a crawl space there, and not habitable space. I doubt there are any applicable door height requirements. They probably wouldn't apply anyway since this is an old home.

Comment: Even though it is an old house, wouldn't changes need to be to current standards?  if I open the door and maybe the windows, which have been blocked too, am I changing it's status as a crawl space?

Answer (score 1):

The Code requires a minimum ceiling height of 7’-0” for habitable spaces, unless 1) it’s a slopped ceiling, 2) basement remodel, 3) bathroom or shower. (See ICC R304.1)

1. Slopped ceilings shall have at least 50% with at least 7’ and slope down to no more than 5’.
2. Basements can have 6’-8” ceilings in non-habitable spaces.
3. Not more than 75% of a sloped ceiling in a bathroom can be less than 7’ if a space in front of toilet, sink, shower is 6’-4” high.

Summary:
Your 6’-2” ceiling height is not acceptable for habitable space. Therefore, the space is considered a crawl space and the “access” needs to be a minimum of 18” x 24”. ((See ICC 1209.1)